# Cronjob issue in nest js

Tags: cron, nestjs

I am facing a weird issue with my cronjob not firing in nest js

I have this example below

```
@Cron('46 13 01 02 *', {
    timeZone: 'Asia/Singapore',
  })
```

I expect the cron job to fire at 1:46PM, on the 1st of February. However, it doesn't. What am i missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you misconfigured the `cron` timing - note that you need 6 `*` while you have only 5 and also the first one is for seconds.
basically it's that:

```
* * * * * *
| | | | | |
| | | | | day of week
| | | | month
| | | day of month
| | hour
| minute
second (optional)
```

so for your case it should be

```js
@Cron(' 0 46 13 01 02 *', {
    timeZone: 'Asia/Singapore',
  })
```